# Wrong Intent Uri data sharing audio files

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

I'm trying to share an audio(.mp3) from a 3rd app to my android app. When I receive the audio and I get the intent info (Uri soundUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)), the Uri has wrong data. The path is correct but the filename has been renamed with numbers (5348 for example) and no extension, the real filename was AUDIO-6151616.mp3

So, full path is /storage/emulated/0/Download/AUDIO-6151616.mp3 but my Intent Uri is /storage/emulated/0/Download/5348

If I share this audio from another 3rd party app (I’m using file explorer apps) it seems to work fine, but if I use others apps or even “Native” Downloads app (on Moto G) it does not.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "What am I missing?" -- you are missing a [mcve]. My guess is that you are also missing [how to use a `Uri` properly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the [official training docs for sharing](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html). You should always expect `content://` uri's like `content://Download/5348`. Because your suppose to call `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`. So you can just end up using the [ShareCompat.IntentReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ShareCompat.IntentReader.html).

Other recommended research to watch is:

- [Sharing Content (Android Development Patterns S2 Ep 6)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9TunRURWNU)
- [Forget the Storage Permission: Alternatives for sharing and collaborating (Big Android BBQ 2015)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C28pvd2plBA)